# Unable to get Expandable Recyclerview working with MaterialViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-recyclerview

I want to display an expandable listview in the pages of the MaterialViewPager.
However, RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter takes only "RecyclerView.Adapter" as a parameter in its constructor. Also, MaterialViewPagerHelper also registers only 'RecyclerView' class. 
i.e, the library accepts only recyclerviews as input. Hence, I decided to implement a recyclerview which behaves similarly to an expandable listview.
I tried using the following libraries/examples along with MaterialViewPager to get the desired functionality.

1. https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view (Expandable Recyclerview Library)
2. https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview (Expandable Recyclerview Library)
3. https://github.com/anandbose/ExpandableListViewDemo (Custom Implementation of Expandable Recyclerview)

In case of 1 & 3, I was unable to get the parent views to expand.
Even in case of 2, I was unable to get it working

I tried implementing expandable listview in a regular viewpager and it worked. However, it doesn't work with MaterialViewPager.